# replace and filter method in one condition using JavaScript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, filter, replace

I have an array which look like this

```
["home/work/abc.jpg",
 "home/work/fish.pdf",
 "home/work/fish.jpg",
 "home/work/doc/animal.jpg",
 "home/work/doc/animal.pdf"];
```

so I want to filter array which contain ".jpg" extension file so I filtered it out by using

```
 array= array.filter((data)=>{
 return data.indexOf(".jpg")>=0
 });
```

so I got my expected value as

```
[ "home/work/abc.jpg",
  "home/work/fish.jpg",
  "home/work/doc/animal.jpg"
]
```

and I replace "home/work/" by using map function

```
 let rep="home/work/";
 array = array.map((data)=>{
 data.replace(rep,"")
 });
```

and got my value as

```
[ "abc.jpg",
  "fish.jpg",
  "doc/animal.jpg"
]
```

but the problem is I have to use two method to filter and replace them is there any possibility I can merge this two method and minimise my code

```
 array= array.filter((data)=>{
 return data.indexOf(".jpg")>=0
 });

 let rep="home/work/";
 array = array.map((data)=>{
 data.replace(rep,"")
 });
```

expected output

```
[ "abc.jpg",
  "fish.jpg",
  "doc/animal.jpg"
]
```

By using any chaining method ?

Comment: You can chain `array.filter().map()`, but you can't combine them in one function, as they do different things. `filter` returns a new array of different length, and `map` transforms every item in an array.

Comment: Also, the `map` doesn't work because you are not returning anything form the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain off of the filtered array without creating another variable, and by using implicit return to make things more concise:

```js
const filenames = ["home/work/abc.jpg",
 "home/work/fish.pdf",
 "home/work/fish.jpg",
 "home/work/doc/animal.jpg",
 "home/work/doc/animal.pdf"];
const rep="home/work/";
const result = filenames
  .filter(file => file.includes('.jpg'))
  .map(file => file.replace(rep, ''));
console.log(result);
```

To actually do it in a single iteration, you'd have to give up on the chaining, and use `reduce` or a standard iteration method.

```js
const filenames = ["home/work/abc.jpg",
 "home/work/fish.pdf",
 "home/work/fish.jpg",
 "home/work/doc/animal.jpg",
 "home/work/doc/animal.pdf"];
const rep="home/work/";
const result = [];
for (const file of filenames) {
  if (file.includes('.jpg')) result.push(file.replace(rep, ''));
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain same result using the same two method that you've used but inside [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const arr = [
  "home/work/abc.jpg",
  "home/work/fish.pdf",
  "home/work/fish.jpg",
  "home/work/doc/animal.jpg",
  "home/work/doc/animal.pdf",
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.indexOf(".jpg") >= 0) {
    acc.push(curr.replace("home/work/", ""));
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will return the same output you are looking for.
Using both `.map` and `.filter` combined.

```
 let array = array
   .filter((data) => data.indexOf(".jpg")>=0)
   .map((data) => data.replace("home/work/",""))
```